# metabox images outside post (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, image

i have a little problem while getting images from a post to an external page, ex: i want to use lastest post images inside a slider used as header placed to the homepage (i'm using metabox to insert images inside the post and to the card header) what i'm trying to achieve:

[image]

```
<?php
$popularpost = new WP_Query(
array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'publish_date', 'order' => 'DES')
);

$titles = array();
$s_desc = array();
$image = array();
while ( $popularpost->have_posts()) : $popularpost->the_post();

$titles[] = the_title('', '', FALSE); // set third parameter to FALSE.
$s_desc[] = short_desc();
//$image[] = rwmb_meta( 'my_image', array( 'size' => 'large' ));

endwhile;
?>

<div class="blog-masthead">
  <div class="ct-header ct-header--slider ct-slick-custom-dots" id="home">
    <div class="ct-slick-homepage" data-arrows="true" data-autoplay="true">
      <div class="ct-header tablex item" data-background="">
        <div class="ct-u-display-tablex">
          <div class="inner">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6 slider-inner">
                  <h1 class="title animated"><?php echo $titles[0]; ?></h1>
                  <p class="header animated slider-desc"><?php echo $s_desc[0] ?></p>
```